# ofbiz URI MAPPING about n depth

Tags: view, request, ofbiz

```
ofbiz uri mapping 

1.my test source get from 
  1.1 source location : svn co http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/ofbiz/trunk ofbiz /* source location in svn */

2. menu( examlple->ajaxexample )  
   2.1 #location : https://localhost:8443/example/control/authview/findExampleAjax /* location about uri */

3. sample url is follow
   3.1 #uri https://localhost:8443/example/control/authview/findExampleAjax /* location about uri */

4. i want set uri 
   4.1 #https://localhost:8443/example/control/authview/findExampleAjax/* location about uri */
               4.2 #https://localhost:8443/example/control/authview/t1/findExampleAjax
   4.3 #https://localhost:8443/example/control/authview/t1/t2/findExampleAjax



how can i set controller.xml

I do not know request authview/findExampleAjax in controller.xml file 

I can not find authview

how can i mapping nth depth directory( URI )



Thank you
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can map this screen by adding a `<view-map>` in `controller.xml`

```
<view-map name="findExampleAjax" type="screen" 
page="component://example/control/authview/yourScreens.xml#findExampleAjax"/>
```

Here `yourScreens.xml` should contain multiple Screens and you can create a new screen like this

```
<screen name="findExampleAjax">
// Decoration for screen
</screen>
```

and `updateExample` is a service defined in a .xml file that contains services and the location of the file is given in `ofbiz-component.xml`

Comment: Thank you.  your sample is http://localhost:8443/example/control/findExampleAjax  I think difference http://localhost:8443/example/control/authview/findExampleAjax  if I want http://localhost:8443/example/control/test/findExampleAjax how can i config controller.xml

Comment: I did not understand the question. Can you explain more?

Comment: thank you   https://localhost:8443/example/control/authview/findExampleAjax it is real source but i can not find page like  you.    controller.xml file(./specialpurpose/example/webapp/example/WEB-INF/controller.xml)  :   .<view-map name="findExampleAjax" type="screen" page="component://example/widget/example/ExampleAjaxScreens.xml#AjaxExample"/> Please say to me about reverse.

Comment: Can you post your `controller.xml`, `ExampleAjaxScreens.xml` code and the location also?

Comment: I can not add too big.                                                                                        this verison default menu (example->ajaxExample)                                   ======>svn co http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/ofbiz/trunk ofbiz please reference

Comment: do you knoow ofbiz? sifho